# Why didn't Voldemort use Avada Kedavra on Dumbledore during their duel at the Ministry of Magic?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, avada-kedavra

If avada kedavra is unblockable (except when an object comes in between the victim and the castor), why didn't Voldemort use it against Dumbledore during their battle at the Ministry in book 5? Was he just so arragant that he thought he could defeat Dumbledore with other magic, to prove he was superior?

Comment: Voldemort used the Killing Curse multiple times, but keep in mind that Dumbledore is not just standing by idly as he sends out waves of Avada Kedavra. The entire time Dumbledore is moving around (and even apparating) and counterattacking with powerful spells that are extremely difficult to defend against as well (unknown 'gong' spell, fire whip, water sphere, animated statues, etc.). If any of these counters connected successfully, the fight would have been over for Voldemort and so he had to be very defensive himself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He did as described on [wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_in_the_Ministry_Atrium)

> Voldemort again Disapparated and Apparated in the middle of the fountain, sending another Killing Curse at Dumbledore. The snake and the curse nearly struck simultaneously, but Fawkes the phoenix sacrificed himself by diving into the path of the curse. He burst into flames and was immediately reborn as a tiny, featherless phoenix.

Edit:

I was able to find exact part of book in chapter "The Only One He Ever Feared"

Here

> Voldemort raised his wand and another jet of green light streaked at
>   Dumbledore, who turned and was gone in a whirling of his cloak. Next
>   second, he had reappeared behind Voldemort and waved his wand towards
>   the remnants of the fountain. The other statues sprang to life.

Here

> "It was foolish to come here tonight, Tom,' said Dumbledore calmly.
>   The Aurors are on their way".
>
> "By which time I shall be gone, and you will be dead!" spat Voldemort.
>   He sent another killing
>
> curse at Dumbledore butmissed, instead hitting the security guard's
>   desk, which burst into flame.

Here

> Another jet of green light flew from behind the silver shield. This
>   time it was the one-armed centaur, galloping in front of Dumbledore,
>   that took the blast and shattered into a hundred pieces.

And here

> `Look out!' Harry yelled.
>
> But even as he shouted, another jet of green light flew at Dumbledore
>   from Voldemort's wand
>
> and the snake struck
>
> Fawkes swooped down in front of Dumbledore, opened his beak wide and
>   swallowed the jet
>
> of green light whole: he burst into flame and fell to the floor,
>   small, wrinkled and flightless.

Comment: So after Fawkes was hit and reborn, why didn't Voldemort just keep trying until he finally landed one?

Comment: He did, I was able to find book online and copy parts of it here... The entire battle took not more than few minutes, if even so. Voldemort also needed to create diversions and to defend himself. So three killing curses in few minutes if proper attempt to kill Dumbledore

Comment: So basically it boils down to Dumbledore being a great enough wizard to keep out of the way of the curse?

Comment: It's obviously an ineffective spell against someone as talented as Dumbledore. AK is just a relatively slow death bolt, every time he did it he opened himself up to Dumbledore's magics, all of which were more effective in pushing Voldemort back than AK(avoidable.)

Comment: Well yes, if you are a great wizard as Dumbledore you keep away from things that can hurt you.  Same is for Voldemort, he had to conjure silver shield out of nothing to deflect Dumbledore curse which wast even lethal.

Comment: I'll concede to that as a good enough answer. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for not just using Wiki as a source. Good find!

Comment: From the quotes it sounds like Dumbledore wasn't constantly disapparating and apparating as a defensive tactic, but was just relying on a combination of ordinary fleet-footedness and others (Fawkes and the centaur) jumping in the way of killing curses? Seems odd that wizard battles would work that way, especially one involving such a powerful but physically old wizard...are there any references at all to Dumbledore disapparating during the battle?

Comment: I added one more quote but it really all brings down to the best aspects of a wizard. Dumbledore charmed that centaur from a fountain. He befriended  phoenix so it "gave life for him".  But in same chapter Dumbledore did use apparition: "Voldemort raised his wand and another jet of green light streaked at Dumbledore, who turned and was gone in a whirling of his cloak. Next second, he had reappeared behind Voldemort and waved his wand towards the remnants of the fountain. The other statues sprang to life."

Answer (score -2):

Voldemort wanted to humiliate Dumbledore, not kill him directly. Plus the story wouldn't allow it, the book would have been over so quickly.

Voldemort was a dark lord that could have also been killed MANY times with the killing curse, but what story would there be if that happened?

Comment: It wasn't me who down-voted, first of all. But: he did want to kill Dumbledore; that's why he ended up ordering Draco to do so: Dumbledore was in the way and until he was gone he would be hindered again and again in his ultimate plans (turns out he still was partly his own doing). And Voldemort couldn't have been killed many times with the curse because why? The Horcruxes. So no, it has nothing to do with not wanting to kill Dumbledore; it has everything to do with Dumbledore was a great wizard. And the only one Voldemort feared.

Comment: Voldermort did try to kill Dumbledore directly, at least 3 times in that battle. He just wasn't successful at it.